I cannot use voices other than the wavenet series
I can only use the wavenet series voices, and cannot use other voices
code:
def _synthesize_speech(language_code, voice_name, api_key, text=None):

    url = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {
        "input": {"ssml": text},
        "voice": {"languageCode": language_code, "name": voice_name},
        "audioConfig": {"audioEncoding": "MP3"}
    }
    params = {"key": api_key}
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,
                                 params=params, data=json.dumps(data))
        response.raise_for_status() 
        return response.json()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error synthesizing speech: {str(e)}")
        return None

test:
_synthesize_speech('en-US','en-US-Studio-O',api_key,'hello world')

error：
Error synthesizing speech: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=...

more tests:
test =  partial(synthesize_speech,
    api_key = api_key,
    text = 'hello, i am jack',
)

voices = [
                'en-US-Casual-K',  
                'en-US-Journey-D',
                'en-US-Journey-F',
                'en-US-Neural2-A',  
                'en-US-Neural2-C',  
                'en-US-Neural2-D',

                'en-US-Neural2-H',  
                'en-US-Neural2-I',
                'en-US-Studio-O',

                'en-US-Wavenet-H',
                'en-US-Wavenet-I',
                'en-US-Wavenet-B',
                'en-US-Wavenet-C',
                'en-US-Wavenet-D',
                'en-US-Wavenet-E'

            ]
for i in voices:
    test(language_code = 'en-US', voice_name=i, save_path= os.path.join(os.getcwd(),i + '.mp3'))

the result:
enter image description here
Only the voices of the wavenet series successfully generate audio

Bad Request, likely the body of the request is malformed
